# Trigger React event with Chrome developer tools

Tags: reactjs

I want to trigger an event in chrome developer tools but I'm new to react find it harder to do than in JS.

I have this example:

```js
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      form onSubmit = {
        this.handleSubmit
      } >
      <
      label >
      Name:
      <
      input type = "text"
      value = {
        this.state.value
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      /> <
      /label> <
      input type = "submit"
      value = "Submit" / >
      <
      /form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  div > < NameForm / > < NameForm / > < /div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

//  doesn't work since v15.6.0
var ev = new Event('input', {
  bubbles: true
});
document.querySelector('form:first-child input').value = 'Not working';
document.querySelector('form:first-child input').dispatchEvent(ev);

var ev2 = new Event('input', {
  bubbles: true
});
ev2.simulated = true;
document.querySelector('form:last-child input').value = 'With simulated flag';
document.querySelector('form:last-child input').dispatchEvent(ev2);
```

Lets say I want to run something in the console that will trigger the same action as if I pressed the submit button which was a JS equivalent of `.click` on that element.

How do I do this in react?

Update:
The below suggested function didn't work for me, any other suggestions?

Comment: how about `componentDidMount() { window.myDebugCls = this }`? then you can call the methods on your react class instance for this component. This is obviously for debugging only :)

Comment: You should try to avoid direct DOM manipulation as much as possible. There are times where its good, but thats a long story. If you can use the react methods I would recommend that. it helps keep the context of everything in the component lifecycle

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get it, can you use my given example?
Youre saying i should in chrome web tools console mount the class and then invoke the handler functions?